# not enough columns to draw -google charts

Tags: google-visualization

I have tried to pass some array data to google charts but it says not enough columns to draw chart.here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
var someStr = '["JAN","1088626"],["FEB","1478093"],["MAR","1232870"],["APR","1151634"],["MAY","1083623"],["JUN","740591"],["JUL","769227"],["AUG","1162995"],["SEP","951794"],["OCT","884736"],["NOV","500902"],["DEC","1221438"]';

var data1=someStr.replace(/(["'])(\d+)\1/g,"$2")
console.log(data1);
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['year'],[data1]]);
console.log(data);
    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities',
      is3D: true,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me to do this.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data has two columns: Month and a Number. (`"JAN","1088626"`)
But you're only providing a header for one column: `year`
Plus, you need to pass an actual `array` to `arrayToDataTable`. (not a string)
Try something like this...

```js
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var someStr = '["JAN","1088626"],["FEB","1478093"],["MAR","1232870"],["APR","1151634"],["MAY","1083623"],["JUN","740591"],["JUL","769227"],["AUG","1162995"],["SEP","951794"],["OCT","884736"],["NOV","500902"],["DEC","1221438"]';

    var data1 = JSON.parse('[' + someStr.replace(/(["'])(\d+)\1/g,"$2") + ']');
    
    // data array - add two column headings to data1
    data1.splice(0, 0, ['month', 'number']);
    
    // data table
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data1);
    
    // chart options
    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities',
      is3D: true
    };

    // chart
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error since invalid input data is passed into `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable` function. The provided regex `/(["'])(\d+)\1/g` fails while parsing the input string,  i would suggest to parse input string with `JSON.parse` function.

> `google.visualization.PieChart` object expects data to be provided in
>   the following format:
>
> ```
> var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
>       ['Name', 'Value'],
>       ['<name1>',  <value1>],
>       ['<name2>',  <value2>],
>       ['<name3>',  <value3>],
>       ...
>       ['<namen>',  <valuen>]
>     ]);
> ```

Below is provided the *modified* example:

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    var stringData = '["JAN","1088626"],["FEB","1478093"],["MAR","1232870"],["APR","1151634"],["MAY","1083623"],["JUN","740591"],["JUL","769227"],["AUG","1162995"],["SEP","951794"],["OCT","884736"],["NOV","500902"],["DEC","1221438"]';
    var data = JSON.parse("[" + stringData + "]");
    data = data.map(function (item) {
        item[1] = parseInt(item[1]);
        return item;
    });
    data.splice(0, 0, ['year', 'hours']);
   
    var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
    var options = {
        title: 'My Daily Activities',
        is3D: true,
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_3d'));
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="piechart_3d" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```